# Gunicorn Excessive resource usage: Resource: Process Time

Tags: nginx, resources, centos7, gunicorn

I'm using Gunicorn 19.8.1, Nginx 1.12.2 and Centos 7.5.1804.
Every hour i receive four emails from my Web server:

```
Time:         Sat Jun 23 08:00:29 2018 +0200
Account:      user
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     48863 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/python2.7
Command Line: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --name user --timeout 60 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
PID:          28455 (Parent PID:28449)
Killed:       No
```

I suppose that there are four emails because i have four gunicorn proccesses?

```
[root@server ~]# ps ax | grep gunicorn
14284 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
28449 ?        Ss     0:16 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --name user --timeout 60 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
28454 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --name user --timeout 60 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
28455 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --name user --timeout 60 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
28456 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --name user --timeout 60 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
```

I'm new to Gunicorn and Nginx so i really dont know why is this happening. I-ve added `--timeout 60` setting to gunicorn.service with hope that this excessive resource usage will stop, but nothing has changed except that emails are generated now on precisely every hour, although `--timeout 60` kills and restarts worker on every 60 seconds not minutes.
This is `etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file content:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/public_html/project
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn.err.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is my `server` block from `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
...
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.net www.example.net;

        location /static/ {
            root /home/user/myproject;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/public_html/project/project.sock;
        }
    }
...
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?